# JComponent not draggable under GridBagConstraints

Tags: java, layout-manager, graphics2d, gridbaglayout, jcomponent

I'm currently making a puzzle game, my design is to have the puzzle(a 3*3 Board)show up on top, and my nine pieceComponents on the bottom in a row as my original state, I want to be able to drag my pieceComponents on to the board so I have them in side the same JPanel. I was suggested to use GridBagConstraints for this to happen, however, for my puzzle board this is a giant space on top, and only the last PieceComponent I added to the screen shows up, also the I believe it is the GridBagConstraints that prevented me from using my mouse to drag the PieceComponents(which I have made draggable),

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Display extends JComponent {
private PuzzleDisplay puzzle;
private JFrame frame;
private static List<PieceComponent> pieces = new ArrayList<PieceComponent>();
private JPanel puzzlePanel;
private GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();


/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display d = new Display();
    d.GUI();
}



/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public Display() {
    puzzle = new PuzzleDisplay();
}

private void PuzzlePanel() {
    puzzlePanel = new JPanel();
    puzzlePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy =0;
    puzzlePanel.add(puzzle, gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    puzzlePanel.add(puzzle.getPieces().get(0), gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    puzzlePanel.add(puzzle.getPieces().get(0), gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 2;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    puzzlePanel.add(puzzle.getPieces().get(0), gbc);
    gbc.gridx = 3;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    puzzlePanel.add(puzzle.getPieces().get(0), gbc);
    puzzlePanel.setVisible(true);
}


public void GUI() {
    frame = new JFrame("Puzzle");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(850, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    PuzzlePanel();
    frame.add(puzzlePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

}
```

this is my PieceComponent class, I made it draggable.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;

public class PieceComponent extends JComponent {
private Piece piece;
private BufferedImage myImage;
private volatile int screenX = 0;
private volatile int screenY = 0;
private volatile int myX = 0;
private volatile int myY = 0;
public PieceComponent(Side top, Side right, Side bottom, Side left, String path) {
    piece = new Piece(top, right, bottom, left);
    try {
        myImage = ImageIO.read((new FileInputStream(path)));
    } catch (IOException exp) {
        exp.printStackTrace();
    }
    addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            screenX = e.getXOnScreen();
            screenY = e.getYOnScreen();
            myX = getX();
            myY = getY();
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            piece.rotateClockwise();
            repaint();
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
    addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
            int deltaX = e.getXOnScreen() - screenX;
            int deltaY = e.getYOnScreen() - screenY;
            setLocation(myX + deltaX, myY + deltaY);
        }
        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        }
    });
}

//returns the chosen side
public Side getSide(Direction direction) {
    return piece.getSide(direction);
}

public Piece getPiece() {
    return piece;
}

public int getHeight() {
    return myImage.getHeight();
}

public int getWidth() {
    return myImage.getWidth();
}


protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (myImage != null) {
        AffineTransform trans = new AffineTransform();
        trans.translate(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2);
        trans.rotate(piece.getOrientation() * Math.PI / 2);
        trans.translate(-myImage.getWidth() / 2, -myImage.getHeight() / 2);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.drawImage(myImage, trans, null);
    }
}
public void rotateClockwise() {
    piece.rotateClockwise();
}
```

This is my PuzzleDisplay

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class PuzzleDisplay extends JComponent{
private Puzzle puzzle;
private JFrame frame;
private List<PieceComponent> pieceComponents = new ArrayList<PieceComponent>();
private List<Piece> pieces = new ArrayList<Piece>();


/**
 * Create the application.
 */
public PuzzleDisplay() {
    pieceComponents.add(new PieceComponent(Side.SPADE_OUT, Side.HEART_OUT, Side.DIAMOND_IN, Side.SPADE_IN, "res/piece_1.png"));
    pieceComponents.add(new PieceComponent(Side.CLUB_OUT, Side.DIAMOND_OUT, Side.CLUB_IN, Side.HEART_IN, "res/piece_2.png"));
    pieceComponents.add(new PieceComponent(Side.HEART_OUT, Side.CLUB_OUT, Side.CLUB_IN, Side.SPADE_IN, "res/piece_3.png"));
    pieceComponents.add(new PieceComponent(Side.CLUB_OUT, Side.DIAMOND_OUT, Side.SPADE_IN, Side.SPADE_IN, "res/piece_4.png"));
    pieceComponents.add(new PieceComponent(Side.CLUB_OUT, Side.CLUB_OUT, Side.HEART_IN, Side.SPADE_IN, "res/piece_5.png"));
    pieceComponents.add(new PieceComponent(Side.HEART_OUT, Side.DIAMOND_OUT, Side.DIAMOND_IN, Side.HEART_IN, "res/piece_6.png"));
    pieceComponents.add(new PieceComponent(Side.CLUB_OUT, Side.DIAMOND_OUT, Side.HEART_IN, Side.DIAMOND_IN, "res/piece_7.png"));
    pieceComponents.add(new PieceComponent(Side.SPADE_OUT, Side.HEART_OUT, Side.CLUB_IN, Side.HEART_IN, "res/piece_8.png"));
    pieceComponents.add(new PieceComponent(Side.DIAMOND_OUT, Side.SPADE_OUT, Side.SPADE_IN, Side.DIAMOND_IN, "res/piece_9.png"));
    for(int i=0; i<pieceComponents.size(); i++) {
        pieces.add(pieceComponents.get(i).getPiece());
    }
    puzzle = new Puzzle(3, pieces);
}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    int imageSize = pieceComponents.get(0).getHeight();
    int boardBuffer = (getWidth()-3*imageSize)/2;
    for(int i=0; i<puzzle.getCols(); i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<puzzle.getRows(); j++) {
            g2d.drawRect(i*imageSize, j*imageSize, imageSize, imageSize);
        }
    }
}

//returns the list of all pieces
public List<PieceComponent> getPieces(){
    return pieceComponents;
}

//Fills the puzzle with the correct solution
public void solve() {
    puzzle.solve();
}

//Determines whether the puzzle has been completed
public boolean isSolved() {
    return puzzle.isSolved();
}

//Determines whether a piece will fit at the specified
//location
public boolean doesFit(PieceComponent pc, int row, int col) {
    return puzzle.doesFit(pc.getPiece(), row, col);
}

//returns the Piece at the specified location
public Piece getPiece(int row, int col) {
    return puzzle.getPiece(row, col);
}

//replaces a Piece at the given location and returns the old Piece
public Piece setPiece(Piece piece, int row, int col) {
    return puzzle.setPiece(piece, row, col);
}

//removes and returns the Piece at the given location
public Piece removePiece(int row, int col) {
    return removePiece(row, col);
}

//Clears the board and puts all pieces back into the piece list
public void reset() {
    puzzle.reset();
}

//returns a List of any pieces not already on the board
public List<Piece> getUnused(){
    return puzzle.getUnused();
}

//returns the number of rows
public int getRows() {
    return puzzle.getRows();
}

//returns the number of columns
public int getCols() {
    return puzzle.getCols();
}

 @Override
 public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
     return new Dimension(pieceComponents.get(0).getHeight()*3, pieceComponents.get(0).getHeight()*3);
 }



/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    PuzzleDisplay d = new PuzzleDisplay();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Puzzle");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(1250, 600);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.add(d);
}
```

}

Comment: Where is `PuzzleDisplay` ? Please show a [**MCVE**](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @YassinHajaj I updated my question

Comment: this will not run; why dont you create the GUI first as a nice board to show then worry about draggable etc - Can you create the board?? that is the question - show me

Comment: GridBagLayout is a terrible layout - use GridLayout() put the pieces there and show the result